# My inside if else is not working. Its just showing approve in all cases

Tags: php, comparison, operators

```
<?php if ($data['status'] = 'pending') { ?>
    <a href="approve.php?id=<?php echo $data['id'];?>"><button Class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Approve</button></a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="approve.php?id=<?php echo $data['id'];?>"><button Class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Approved</button></a>
<?php } ?>
```

This code is to print "approve" if user is not approved and print "approved" if user is already approved, but it's not working, showing approve in all cases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
if($data['status']='pending')
```

To

```
if($data['status']=='pending')
```

**Edit**:

```
if($data['status'] === 'pending')
```

Will check the value as well as types.

For more info, click [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: worth noting that `==` is a loose comparison that doesn't regard var_types `===` is strict and matches value and var_type

Comment: Thankew so much.. its just slipped from my mind, btw thankew so much :)

Comment: It was a typo @Deepak. If you think, this answer helped you. Then, please mark this answer as a correct answer. It will help other user to find this easily.

Answer (score 2):

Insted of this

```
if($data['status']='pending')
```

use

```
if($data['status']==='pending')
```

For also check datatype.

Answer (score 1):

insted of this

'=' assignment operator

```
if($data['status']='pending')
```

use this code

'=='Comparison operators

```
if($data['status']=='pending')
```